# What is the mips-command to load 4 bytes at the same time into a register?

Tags: assembly, command, byte, mips

the question is simple:
What is the command to load 4 bytes in a register?

Could this work?

lui $t0,255

ori $t0,$t0,255

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. You load the top 16 bits first, then bring the low 16 in. Your code as shown will of course produce `0x00ff00ff` in `$t0`. It's not clear whether you wanted that or not. It's also a somewhat unconventional definition of "at the same time". PS: most assemblers have a `la` pseudoinstruction so you can do `la $t0, 0x00ff00ff`. `gas` will generate the code shown from that.

Comment: Hey!
First thanks for your help:


I have already thought about la, but i never understood how this command works.

Comment: `la` specifically does what you asked - it allows to load an address and the size of addresses is 32 bits. It's not a real instruction though, the assembler will generate code for it, and my version of `gas` actually produces the code you showed.

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: there's no direct instruction to load 32 bits in single step, because MIPS has 32 bit wide instruction words (and that size is fixed), so if you reserve even just single one bit to encode instruction(s), you are left with only 31 bits for value, already 1 bit missing. (and 1 bit for instructions is not enough of course, that allows only for two combinations in total). So that's why these loads on MIPS are either composed from instructions like `lui+ori`, or the values are loaded from memory if you have already some address pointing to/near them.

Comment: if you want to load a value in a single instruction you need to have that value in memory and load from memory.  Generically you cannot load any 32 bit immediate into a register in a single instruction (there are pseudo instructions which are not single instructions but two for most constants).   There are constants that will work, ones that you can do a single lui for (lower 16 bits zeros right) and/or an ori with (uppoer 16 bits zeros), otherwise it is two instructions and the register is probably loaded in two steps.

Answer (score -1):

```
lw $t, offset($s)
```

loads the 4 byte word into a Coprocessor data register. MIPS I has instructions that load and store 8-bit bytes, 16-bit halfwords, and 32-bit words. Word is always 32-bit (4 byte) that's why you definitely need this pseudo instruction for your homework (it is homework, isn't it?)

I suppose we are doing the same homework currently so I'd say the solution, that you suggested fits better to 1.4. :)